# Core Data Save dangling object before sqlite export issue

Tags: core-data

I have a object that gets created. A export sqlite method runs before that object can get saved properly to the managed object context.

So, because the object is dangling the app crashes. How do I actually make sure that the dangling object gets saved before the export runs?

This save method is called before the export:

```
-(void)saveContext {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = 
    self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext 
            save:&error]) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your core data stack look like?  Is the write taking place in a background context?

Comment: Sound like the persistent store coordinator is trying to access the file at the same time. I don't think that it is every safe to access the file while the store has a pointer to it.   Have you tried removing the store before doing the export.  You would lose the data that is in memory at the time, but I don't think it will crash.